# Insert query in mysql using metadata

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sql-insert

I have a list which consists of the column name of a table

```
String tableName="employee";
ResultSet rs = Statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM"+tableName);
    ResultSetMetaData   rmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = rmd.getColumnCount();
        List columnsList = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            columnsList.add(rmd.getColumnName(i));
        }
```

List values=[some values];

```
now columnsList =[emp_id, name, salary, department];
```

now i want to write insert query using these column names.But i don't want to hard code the column name i want to get these names from the list and to pass them to column names like

```
   String subQuery= "insert into"+tableName+......here i want to get column names from list.....+.......here values from another list......;
```

is there any way to get this

Comment: Needed space between  "FROM " and tableName
ResultSet rs = Statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+tableName);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the column names in a `List` then you can use `StringUtils.join` from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) to build a comma-separated list and include that in your SQL statement:

```java
// the following code assumes: import org.apache.commons.lang.*;
String tableName="employee";
List<String> columnsList = new ArrayList<String>();
columnsList.add("emp_id");  //
columnsList.add("name");    // sample data
columnsList.add("salary");  //
String colString = StringUtils.join(columnsList, ',');
String paramString = StringUtils.repeat(",?", columnsList.size());
String sql = String.format(
        "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)", 
        tableName, colString, paramString.substring(1));
System.out.println(sql);
```

resulting in

```sql
INSERT INTO employee (emp_id,name,salary) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

**Edit:** Note that for safety's sake you probably should enhance the above code to enclose the table and column names in backticks, e.g.

```sql
INSERT INTO `employee` (`emp_id`, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Been Googling my #@$ of looking for a code shippet to dynamically generate a JDBC insert statement form meta data. Refer to [generateInsertStatements()](http://www.xinotes.net/notes/note/632/)

```
private static void generateInsertStatements(Connection conn, String tableName)
throws Exception {
    log("Generating Insert statements for: " + tableName);
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName); 
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    int[] columnTypes = new int[numColumns];
    String columnNames = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
        columnTypes[i] = rsmd.getColumnType(i + 1);
        if (i != 0) {
            columnNames += ",";
        }
        columnNames += rsmd.getColumnName(i + 1);
    }

    java.util.Date d = null; 
    PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tableName + "_insert.sql"));
    p.println("set sqlt off");
    p.println("set sqlblanklines on");
    p.println("set define off");
    while (rs.next()) {
        String columnValues = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                columnValues += ",";
            }

            switch (columnTypes[i]) {
                case Types.BIGINT:
                case Types.BIT:
                case Types.BOOLEAN:
                case Types.DECIMAL:
                case Types.DOUBLE:
                case Types.FLOAT:
                case Types.INTEGER:
                case Types.SMALLINT:
                case Types.TINYINT:
                    String v = rs.getString(i + 1);
                    columnValues += v;
                    break;

                case Types.DATE:
                    d = rs.getDate(i + 1); 
                case Types.TIME:
                    if (d == null) d = rs.getTime(i + 1);
                case Types.TIMESTAMP:
                    if (d == null) d = rs.getTimestamp(i + 1);

                    if (d == null) {
                        columnValues += "null";
                    }
                    else {
                        columnValues += "TO_DATE('"
                                  + dateFormat.format(d)
                                  + "', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')";
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    v = rs.getString(i + 1);
                    if (v != null) {
                        columnValues += "'" + v.replaceAll("'", "''") + "'";
                    }
                    else {
                        columnValues += "null";
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        p.println(String.format("INSERT INTO %s (%s) values (%s)\n/", 
                                tableName,
                                columnNames,
                                columnValues));
    }
    p.close();
}
```

Additional [Metadata Example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/sql/jdbc-databasemetadata-example/):

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the input values same as the number of columns in your table in the same sequence then you need not even provide the column name. For example you can write simply as

insert into  values (val1, val2, .....)

If you don't specify column names then mysql will automatically consider all columns. 
But this approach of writing is a very bad approach which is difficult to maintain and can introduce unexpected bugs.

Comment: yaa i understand but it is mandatory for my application. i have to give permission to user from UI to update few columns or to insert a new record.So can i have any other approach to work on this situation